# Uninstalling 12.10

Tags: 12.10, uninstall

What is the procedure to entirely remove Ubuntu 12.10? I was running Ubuntu 12.04 successfully and was advised that 12.10 was available as an upgrade. I updated 12.04 to 12.10 through the update manager. I have been unhappy with 12.10 from day 1.

I installed a fresh copy of 12.04 to run alongside 12.10 on a separate partition. I am a newbie at this and need to be able to clean the hard drive of all except the new 12.04 and its files.

If this program is this buggy it shouldn't be offered as an update! I just want to clean things up.

Answer (score 1):

Run [gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) and delete the partition that contains your installation of 12.10, then rerun [grub-install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2).  If you are more specific about your bugs in 12.10, someone might be able to help you.  12.10 works fairly well for me.

Comment: That's just it...way too many bugs to even name, and as a newbie, identify.  I can't get any command icons  (left panel) to appear so I can't do anything.  I can get the terminal, but at this stage the only command sequence I want, or need, is the commands to clean 12.10 and all associated files off my HD.  I'm running 12.04 in a seperate partition and it is more than sufficient.  At least until I learn more.

Comment: Okay.  Could you remove the 12.10 partition with gparted?  Note that if you want to extend your 12.04 partition to cover the newly empty space, you will have to run gparted from live media (or with your 12.04 partition unmounted).